# Does Kotest (previously KotlinTest) still work in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlintest, kotest

As far as I can tell, Kotest requires JUnit 5:

https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/1104

It also requires Gradle 6:

https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/1301

I presume it's possible to get this all set up and working, but isn't it true that JUnit 5 and Gradle 6 are not really supported for Android development? I'm concerned that, even I get this all working now, I may have problems down the line.

Comment: In the second link, it is mentioned that Kotest 4.0 is out, what else have you tried?

Comment: I don't quite see what the version number of Kotest has to do with my question. I'm asking whether I can rely on JUnit 5 and Gradle 6 working for Android development, because as far as I know neither is officially supported.

Comment: Gradle 6 is fine, you can use Junit 4.13.

Comment: How do you use JUnit 4 with Kotest? As far as I can see, this is possible only for older versions that existed when the project was called Kotlintest.

Answer (score 2):

Kotest **does** work on Android Studio.

#### JVM tests

To setup the JUnit 5 runner for your unit tests (plain JVM) you can follow the instructions at https://kotest.io/quick_start/.

Of course If you have an already started project with JVM JUnit4 tests you will have to make additional steps to configure both the runners for the JUnit4 **and** for the new JUnit5/Kotest tests, but it is outside of the scope of this answer.

#### Android **Robolectric** tests

You can find the instructions on how to set it up [here](https://kotest.io/extensions/#roboelectric). Given Robolectric ones are plain JVM tests and not instrumented ones, you can use the JUnit5 runner and they will run just fine.

#### Android instrumented tests

Apparently Kotest has a JUnit4 runner project too, but no instructions yet on how to set it up with Android.